# Is Google App Engine tmp folder isolated per instance?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

There's very little information about the /tmp/ folder which App Engine can use to write files. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#Java_The_sandbox

The main question is if this is isolated per instance? And if an instance saves a file, starts a push queue, will the push queue be ran by the same instance and able to read the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `/tmp` directory actually exists in memory, so it is local to each GAE instance. From the doc you quoted:

> Files in `/tmp` will consume the memory allocated to your instance.

Typically the execution of a push queue task is not guaranteed to happen on the same instance that enqueued the task.

This guarantee can only exist in a very specific, rather not typical case: you use manual scaling with exactly one instance running and that instance both enqueues the task and (later) processes it.

Comment: Can confirm, when logging instance id (ModulesServiceFactory.getModulesService().getCurrentInstanceId()) there _sometimes_ a different instance for wrtiting file at request and reading file in push queue. But this only happens when there's a large file and at App Engine, not for smaller files or locally. Seems that first instance is busy writing file and a second instance is starting the push queue at the same time.

Comment: You can encounter much more often the case if you have multiple instances running or if your tasks are delayed/deferred long enough for the enqueuing instance to disappear